# Laravel Messed up Homestead Permissions

Tags: linux, laravel, file-permissions

I seem to have messed up Homestead's Linux Permissions, my app is throwing exceptions like not being able to find views that are there and "Impossible to create Root Directory".

I did do a recursive `chmod` a little while ago which i think is the cause of the problem, the issue is i don't quite know how to revert that.

In my `after.sh` Homestead script i'm setting the following Provisioning rules

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/vagrant/Code/myapp
sudo usermod -a -G www-data vagrant

sudo find /home/vagrant/Code/myapp -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
sudo find /home/vagrant/Code/myapp -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

sudo chgrp -R www-data /home/vagrant/Code/myapp/storage /home/vagrant/Code/myapp/bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx /home/vagrant/Code/myapp/storage /home/vagrant/Code/myapp/bootstrap/cache
```

I execute those and nothing happens, it's still getting the same errors, so i went and checked **NGINXs** `nginx.conf` file and it's referencing `vagrant` as it's user so that's correct...

And calling `ls -lsa` on my root project folder *(inside of the Vagrant VM)* returns the following information. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

```
   0 drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant   1280 Dec 18 13:59 .
  4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root    root      4096 Dec 18 13:29 ..
  4 -rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant   1771 Dec 18 13:59 after.sh
  8 -rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant   7314 Nov 21 09:24 aliases
  0 drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant    320 Dec 17 17:39 app
  4 -rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant   1646 Nov 21 09:24 artisan
  0 drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant    160 Dec 12 17:01 bootstrap
  4 -rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant   1707 Dec 17 17:51 composer.json
172 -rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 175864 Dec 18 13:24 composer.lock
  0 drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant    544 Dec 18 13:50 config
  4 -rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant   1534 Nov 21 09:24 CONTRIBUTING.md
  8 -rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant   7970 Dec 16 20:33 _custom_ide_helper.php
  0 drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant    192 Dec 12 16:40 database
  8 -rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant   6148 Dec 14 16:31 .DS_Store
  4 -rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant    627 Dec  4 12:34 .env
  4 -rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant    499 Dec  4 17:29 .env.example
  0 drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant    480 Dec 18 14:02 .git
  4 -rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant     61 Nov 21 09:24 .gitattributes
  4 -rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant    154 Nov 21 09:24 .gitignore
  4 -rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant   1278 Dec 14 08:58 .gitlab-ci.yml
  4 -rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant   2389 Dec 18 00:10 gruntfile.js
  4 -rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant    335 Dec 12 10:26 Homestead.yaml
  0 drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant    544 Dec 18 14:01 .idea
512 -rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 464272 Dec 18 13:53 _ide_helper.php
  0 drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant  24704 Dec 18 00:03 node_modules
  4 -rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant   2164 Dec 18 00:03 package.json
380 -rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 385087 Dec 18 00:03 package-lock.json
128 -rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant  93326 Dec 18 13:53 .phpstorm.meta.php
  4 -rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant   1190 Dec 15 10:28 phpunit.xml
  0 drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant    320 Dec 12 12:34 public
  4 -rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant    855 Dec 12 10:26 readme.md
  0 drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant    160 Nov 21 09:24 resources
  0 drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant    128 Dec 17 16:57 routes
  4 -rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant    563 Nov 21 09:24 server.php
  0 drwxrwxr-x 1 vagrant vagrant    256 Dec 18 13:50 storage
  0 drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant    224 Dec 17 13:42 tests
  0 drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant     96 Dec 18 13:27 .vagrant
  4 -rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant   1376 Nov 21 09:24 Vagrantfile
  0 drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant   1280 Dec 18 13:25 vendor
204 -rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 208270 Dec 18 13:50 yarn.lock
```

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out, for some reason in my /bootstrap/cache directory, laravel was referencing paths on my host machine instead of my vagrant box, clearing this directory did the trick for me. For some reason `php artisan cache:clear` didn't clear these files.

I've also set up a provisioning script to delete these files for me everytime i provision my Vagrant Box.

```
# Remove Cache Files (because old cache files can cause issues from time to time)  [Keep .gitignore in all Directories]
sudo find "$APPPATH/bootstrap/cache" ! -name '.gitignore' -type f -exec rm -f {} +
sudo find "$APPPATH/storage/framework/cache" ! -name '.gitignore' -type f -exec rm -f {} +
sudo find "$APPPATH/storage/framework/sessions" ! -name '.gitignore' -type f -exec rm -f {} +
sudo find "$APPPATH/storage/framework/testing" ! -name '.gitignore' -type f -exec rm -f {} +
sudo find "$APPPATH/storage/framework/views" ! -name '.gitignore' -type f -exec rm -f {} +
```